# Cannot commit changes with gitextensions

Tags: git

I'm trying to commit my changes to our master and this seems a little harder to me using VS13 and Git now, than VS and TFS...

I changed one .cs file and wanted to commit my changes to sync it afterwards.
When I click "pull" it tells me "Repository is already up to date. No changes to pull."

But when I click commit i get: "An error occurred. Detailed message: Cannot create a tree from a not fully merged index."

I tryed to google this error, but I cannot really find anything helpful.

Does anybody know what I#M doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT: I dont know if this is relevant or not, but last friday I unstashed(?) some changes I stashed a week before or so. Those changes are still there, I just fixed some minor bug and excluded all other changes for this commit.

Comment: What `git status` return?

Comment: @VonC I'm sorry what do you mean by git status? I only see the error message inside my Team Explorer. Where can I find the `git status`?

Comment: It is always preferable to fallback to the command line when the GUI (here Visual Studio) does not make sense. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/03/08/use-the-git-command-prompt-to-supplement-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 16):

In Visual Studio, right to `Commit` button, press `Actions` and choose `Open Command Prompt`. Git console window will show up. Run `git status` command to see which files are going to be committed.

According to your situation there should be something in `Unmerged paths` section. Add this unmerged files to your changes using `git add [file_name]` command, than open file in Visual Studio and modify it leaving correct version of changes.

Comment: What if I do not want to commit the changes from the so-called merged files?? (They are web.config files that I keep different only on my local.) How can I just undo them? They aren't appearing in the change list in visual studio, and `git reset HEAD` isn't doing anything either.

Comment: tanx dear user for ur usefull answer :)