# Git "Cannot create a tree from a not fully merged index"

Tags: git, visual-studio

I changed a long list of files in Visual Studio 2013, and am now trying to commit them as well as sync them with the changes that others have made (We are using bitbucket, if that makes a difference). When trying to commit, I entered the commit message, but then get the error

> "An error occurred. Detailed message: Cannot create a tree from a not
>   fully merged index. "

I am not very experienced with git, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804352/cannot-commit-changes-with-gitextensions Check your status (with `git status`), add the unmerged paths, commit.

Answer (score 38):

I just had this same problem. [Raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) linked to the answer, but to elaborate here: open a git Bash in your working directory and run `git status`. From there, you will see what your problems are.

For me, it's often because of a unresolved merge conflict. If there are unmerged paths and you want to use your local changes, i.e. mark which files are the conflict resolution, run `git add [filePath\fileName]`.

If you want to discard the changes, i.e. unstage the file, use `git reset HEAD [filePath\fileName]`.

Comment: Did you mean "an unresolved merge conflict"?  (This error occurs when an index is not fully merged, ie, there are merge conflicts in the index.)

Comment: That seems to be the root of the problem, but the literal error text is as above in Jesse's question.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. git status command has clearly informed about un-merged paths, once that is resolved, next commit worked well. Thanks.